# Angular suscribed observable don't showing information on the view

Tags: node.js, angular, observable

[image of the detail view with console to see the console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ONOK.png)
I'm having troubles making the Tour Of Heroes Angular tutorial work, i'm in the 6 step of the tutorial, getting the data from a server but instead of getting the data from a simulated data server i have a api with nodejs express and mysql.

The problem cames when i try to show the detail of the hero (fetching one by id), all seems to work but the information don't show on the view.

template:

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{ hero.name }} Details</h2>
    <div>id: {{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Hero name: </label>
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
</div>
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
  }

  getHero(){
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id"));
    this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => {
      this.hero = hero;
      console.log("hero", hero)
    })
  }
```

service:

```
  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:3300/api/';

  constructor(private MessageService: MessageService, private http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.MessageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
  }
  
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]>{
    this.log('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl);
  }


getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Hero>(url);
}
```

I don't know what's the problem, im learning angular but the observable is well suscribed, in the attached image you can see in the console that at least the api is working.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? You could be getting a CORS error since your backend runs on a different port.

Comment: no errors on the console. the template is displaying its content, it has an *ngif and the variable is not initialized in componen, you need to suscribe it to be able to see the detail template and its showing , I made even a console.log of the suscribed variable and the information is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you received an array with an unique element, see the ``` [``] ``` in console. So

**Or** in subscribe your write `hero[0]`

```
  this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => {
      this.hero = hero[0];
    })
```

**Or** in your service return the first element of the array. For this use rxjs/operator map

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(url).pipe(
        map((res:Hero[])=>res[0])
      );
}
```

See that although you say to Angular that getHero return an `Observable<Hero>` really you got an `Observable<Hero[]>`. Yes, when we indicate the return of a function this **not** make "magically" we get the result, only help us to write the code and the editor advise us about it

Comment: yeah, the firts option plus some changes in the service made it work. thank you very much.